# Inferno AesCtrCryptoTransform

Tags: ssh, cryptography, aes

Can anyone provide a usage example of [SecurityDriven.Inferno AesCtrCryptoTransfom](http://securitydriven.net/inferno/#AES-CTR%20Transform) class ?

The library seems very promising but I am unable to find any code using it and the supplied details are not enough for me crypto-dummy...

I am extending an application that works perfectly with many ciphers, only it does not support AES counter mode. I would need this aes-128-ctr cipher for some SSHv2 sessions. 
The application has a very simple Cipher interface for all of the different ciphers, like below :

```
  internal interface Cipher
  {
    void Encrypt(byte[] data, int offset, int len, byte[] result, int result_offset);
    void Decrypt(byte[] data, int offset, int len, byte[] result, int result_offset);
    int BlockSize { get; }
  }
```

I created an implementaion of the interface using AesCtrCryptoTransform as below but it does not work.

```
public class AES128CTR : Cipher
{
  private System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform Encryptor;
  private ArraySegment<Byte> _counter;

  public AES128CTR(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
  {
    _counter = new ArraySegment<byte>(iv);
    Encryptor = new SecurityDriven.Inferno.Cipher.AesCtrCryptoTransform(key, _counter);
  }

  public int BlockSize { get { return Encryptor.InputBlockSize; } }

  public void Decrypt(byte[] data, int offset, int len, byte[] result, int result_offset)
  {
    Encryptor.TransformBlock(data, 0, len, result, 0);
  }

  public void Encrypt(byte[] data, int offset, int len, byte[] result, int   result_offset)
  {
    Encryptor.TransformBlock(data, 0, len, result, 0);
  }
}
```

This should be farily easy and I must be making obvious mistakes only can't figure them out. Any ideas please how to do this right ?

Comment: I applaud the effort of posting the code, but "it does not work" is still the worst error description. You've created an *adapter* for the TLS implementation, but it is unlikely that the code *within* the adapter is at fault. So I don't think this is enough info for us to debug the TLS session, and even if it was, SO really is not well suited for online debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working solution:

```
  public class AES128CTR : Cipher
  {
    private byte[] _key;
    private byte[] _iv;

    public AES128CTR(byte[] key, byte[] iv, int KeySize = 128)
    {
      this._key = key;
      this._iv = iv;
    }

    public int BlockSize { get { return _iv.Length; } }

    public void Decrypt(byte[] data, int offset, int len, byte[] result, int result_offset)
    {
      SecurityDriven.Inferno.Cipher.AesCtrCryptoTransform transformation = new SecurityDriven.Inferno.Cipher.AesCtrCryptoTransform(_key, new ArraySegment<byte>(_iv));
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream cs = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(ms, transformation, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
          cs.Write(data, offset, len);
        }
        var r = ms.ToArray();
        Array.Copy(r, result, r.Length);
      }
    }

    public void Encrypt(byte[] data, int offset, int len, byte[] result, int result_offset)
    {
      SecurityDriven.Inferno.Cipher.AesCtrCryptoTransform transformation = new SecurityDriven.Inferno.Cipher.AesCtrCryptoTransform(_key, new ArraySegment<byte>(_iv));
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream cs = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(ms, transformation, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
          cs.Write(data, offset, len);
        }
        var r = ms.ToArray();
        Array.Copy(r, result, r.Length);
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed. Just the `Decrypt()` needs some tweaking: The `MemoryStream` you pass into the `CryptoStream` should contain the cipher text (`data` parameter) and the mode should be `CryptoStreamMode.Read`. Then you would call `cs.Read()` instead of `cs.Write()`.